# Finding ways to consume an API in springboot 3.1.4

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven

I want to find ways for consuming other APIs using springboot3.1.4

I have looked into Webclient and RestTemplate but RestTemplate is now in maintenance mode and WebClient is asynchronous. Spring introduces RestClient in 3.2.0 milestone which I cannot currently use. I looked into FeignClient but I haven't found enough resources. Are there any other ways to consume APIs?

Comment: And what is the problem with `WebClient`? The fact that `RestTemplate` is in maintance mode doesn't mean you cannot use it, it isn't deprecated.

Comment: You can also use java's default client comes with java 9.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/java-9-http-client

Comment: Use RestTemplate in Spring 3.1.* and with Spring Boot 3.2+ migrate to RestClient...

Comment: From what I am aware of, WebClient needs some additional server setup but for me I need it to run on Apache Tomcat.Forgive me if I am mistaken @M.Deinum

Comment: You are mistaken.

Comment: I went through the documentation again and I read that I can indeed use it on Tomcat server. Thanks @M.Deinum

Comment: The webclient or any other client doesn't need a server, it is a client. You can use it from a standalone java application as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want asynchronous client - Feign is the best option in my opinion.

It is quite simple to use, and it is well documented in the official Spring documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-openfeign/docs/current/reference/html/